# What's the minimum required number of playthroughs needed to get all trophies/achievements?

Tags: achievements, mass-effect-3

I'm the type of person who likes to get all the trophies/achievements when playing games.
Setting out to play Mass Effect 3, which is probably a rather long game, I'd wish to get all trophies/achievements on my first playthorugh, although I don't know if that's possible.

Can you get all trophies/achievements for Mass Effect 3 in on your first playthrough or are multiple playthroughs required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently saw a trophy-list for the PS3-Trophies - unless you have an Import-Savegame from ME2, you need to finish the game twice (The trophy actually says: finish game twice or once with imported savegame), and there's also an achievement to finish the game on a certain difficulty-level, and I don't know whether you can chose it from the beginning or need to unlock it first.

Most trophies seem to be story-related, so I don't know if you can get them on one run, but my guess would be that one run is enough (if you have the imported savegame stated before).

Comment: I only have a German source for that, I don't know if it makes much sense to add it here.

Comment: This is not correct unfortunately.

Answer (score 3):

The absolute minimum is 2 playthroughs, because you can only upgrade weapons to rank 10 in a second playthrough, even with an imported ME2 character.

Weapons upgraded through the multiplayer store also count toward this achievment

Answer (score 3):

You could do it in one if you import a ME2 character and play it through on insanity without changing the difficulty level. Then play multiplayer to get all the other trophies like upgrading guns. 
I got them all in 2 playthroughs, but I had 2 ME2 characters that I wanted to use,, a soldier and an engineer.

Comment: This is the most correct answer so far, including better than the currently accepted answer by @Junjiru.

Answer (score 1):

Based on my Mass Effect 2 playthrough (which shares many similar non-story trophies with Mass Effect 3), I don't know what the exact "minimum number" would be, but it's certainly not one. Or, if it is one, you have to be very, very good with the powers of your squadmates. There are several trophies based on the way enemies are killed or which powers are used against them.  If Shepard doesn't have those powers, you have to use squadmates that do.  That will take time.  I'd guess two playthroughs would be the minimum, probably with different classes.