# Can you unlock Ability Achievements in one playthrough by using your squad?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Can you unlock all ability achievements (e.g. overload the shields of 100 enemies) with all classes? My character doesn't have some of the abilities, so does telling your squad member to perform it count?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/53533/whats-the-minimum-required-number-of-playthroughs-needed-to-get-all-trophies-ac). If you focus on whether or not your squadmates' abilities count towards achievements, you can probably avoid yours being closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Using squad abilities counts toward the achievement progress.

Comment: I don't know if this is a bug or working as intended, but the achievement for "Overload" doesn't seem to work with squadmates. I have 0/100, despite using Garrus' and EDI's Overload skills many times.

Comment: @FAE: I had the same issue with Overload. However, multiplayer counts, so you can get it quickly by playing a few rounds with a Human Engineer. Overload spam is surprisingly effective, especially against Geth.